# C program-file copy

Tags: c

I've wrote a C code for copying file data from one to another.The following code is working fine.but compiler still shows its a wrong answer as the execution time is high its 280.0,below is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char ch,fname1[20],fname2[20];
    printf("Enter the input file name\n");
    gets(fname1);
    printf("Enter the output file name\n");
    gets(fname2);
    fp1=fopen(fname1,"r");
    fp2=fopen(fname2,"w");
    do
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp1);
        fputc(ch,fp2);
    }
    while(ch!=EOF);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the copy is one byte larger than the original?

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little better?

Comment: BTW [fgetc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) returns an integer - so there is one mistake

Comment: Why dont you use getline()?

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. You write `0xFF` (which as stated is confused with `EOF`) *before* it is tested. Try `int ch; while((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) { fputc(ch,fp2); }`

Comment: To avoid extra byte in copy, use `while((ch=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF)` instead of `do while` loop

Comment: There are other faults with this code too: obsolete `main` signature, use of obsolete `gets`, not checking the result of `fopen` (that one really is *elementary* and *inexcusable*), not calling `fclose` at the end.

Comment: I didn't bother reading the code.  No formatting /indenntation, so downvoting as unclear.  Not that it matters much with a 'Member since today ' :(

Answer (score 1):

Your program will always output the EOF character.

`fgetc` actually doesn't return a character, but an `int`.
EOF is actually -1. When you write it, an extra byte (0xFF) is written to the output file.

A correct code would be like:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
{
    fputc(ch,fp2);
}
```

You could argue for this code's (in)elegance, but the point is that you should **not** print the EOF character.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `fread` to read a significant chunk (at least 4096 bytes, or even as much as 1MB) of the input file, and then write that chunk to the output file with `fwrite`. That can help to reduce the time wasted on [seek time and rotational latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Seek_time) on a spinning hard drive.

Something like this:

```
size_t n;
size_t bufsize = 1024 * 1024;         // one megabyte buffer size
void *buffer = malloc( bufsize );   
if ( buffer != NULL ) {
    while ( (n = fread( buffer, 1, bufsize, fp1 )) != 0 ) {
        fwrite( buffer, 1, n, fp2 );
    }
}
```

And of course, you should fix the problems that @WeatherVane mentioned in the comments.

- main should be declared as `int main( void )`
- never use `gets`, use `fgets` instead
- always check the return value from `fopen`. It can and does fail, e.g. if the input file doesn't exist, or you don't have write permission for the output file
- be sure to close the files with `fclose` when you're done with them